# How to customize IntelliJ's inline documentation pane colors and fonts?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

Is there a way to customize IntelliJ's  inline documentation pane colors and fonts?

The way it is in the picture bellow, makes it hard to read the javadoc text.

[image]

Comment: Guess I'm not the only one...

Comment: This seems to have changed recently. I've looked through all of the `Editor -> Appearance` options and found nothing.

Comment: If you simply want to increase the font size, then a slider is available when you click the cogwheel button in the top right corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug of Intellij IDEA.It had be fixed in IDEA.http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+13.1+135.667+Release+Notes .

Comment: Yeah, seems to have been fixed. Does not happen anymore in version 13.1.4.